# How can you programmatically find out in Xamarin Forms for Android if a device has vibration function?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Does anyone know how to find out this info?

Answer (score 4):

[Xamarin.Essentails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/essentials/vibrate?tabs=android) trows an [FeatureNotSupportedException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.featurenotsupportedexception?view=xamarin-essentials) if vibration is not available, that you can handle:

```
try
{
    // Use default vibration length
    Vibration.Vibrate();
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException ex)
{
    // Feature not supported on device
}
```